# How to get live exchange rate and assign it to an html label element

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to assign a live exchange rate to an html label element.

This is the URL query
https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v4/convert?q=GBP_EUR&compact=ultra

The result is 
{"GBP_EUR":1.122436}

How can I assign the 1.122436 to HTML label?

```html
<div class="table-2">
<table width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" align="center" width="70%"><input id="fundvalueslider" max="1000000" min="0" step="5000" type="range" value="0" /></th>
<th colspan="3" align="left" width="15%"><label id="exratetxt">Exchange Rate =  </label>
<label id="exratetxt2"></label></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: provide your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v4/convert?q=GBP_EUR&compact=ultra');
$jsonData = json_decode($data);
echo $jsonData->GBP_EUR;
?>
```

Use the above PHP code to print the `<label id="exratetxt">Exchange Rate = <?php  echo $jsonData->GBP_EUR; ?> </label>`

[image]

Comment: This code worked to fetch the data which is great. however I cannot get to assign it to the label value using <label id="exratetxt">Exchange Rate = <?php  echo $jsonData->GBP_EUR; ?> </label>

Comment: <?php
$data = file_get_contents('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v4/convert?q=GBP_EUR&compact=ultra');
$jsonData = json_decode($data);
?>
<div class="table-2">
<table width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" align="center" width="70%"><input id="fundvalueslider" max="1000000" min="0" step="5000" type="range" value="0" /></th>
<th colspan="3" align="left" width="15%"><label id="exratetxt">Exchange Rate =  <?php echo $jsonData->GBP_EUR; ?></label>
<label id="exratetxt2"></label></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>

Comment: Above is the complete code you should use and please save your page as filename.php. Please see the attached screenshot. It is working fine

Answer (score 0):

The currency data is in JSON string format.
First you need to fetch the string, you can use PHP (file_get_contents or cURL).
Then parse the JSON string to get the value. use json_decode and access the array to get the data.then you can display the data where you want

Edit: the reason why you need to use PHP to fetch the page is because the website disable the access-control-allow-origin, which is not possible to fetch using javascript ajax. Please correct me if I'm wrong.